# Getting error with react-navigation-stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am using react-navigation and react-navigation-stack in my code. Done everything as told in the react-navigation documentation. Still getting this error. You can see the code and the error in the screenshot below. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Hello Bhupinder and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Can you put your code and your error message as a code snippet, rather than an image? It will help people find it by searching and - more importantly for you in the short term - will be more easily seen by potential answerers, since they can see it directly without clicking on the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to install @react-native-community/masked-view. Because it is used by react-navigation-stack.

Use following command to install both :-

```
npm install react-navigation-stack @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the command in the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html):

```sh
yarn add react-navigation-stack @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Are you sure you have used this command and installed `@react-native-community/masked-view`?

Comment: Installing @react-native-community solved it. Thanks for the help